# Unable to switch encoding error

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jpa, utf-8, websphere-8

**I am facing a strange issue pertaining to UTF-8 encoding.**

Tech Stack- IBM WAS 8.0, IBM JPA jars, SQL Server 2008

I have same application deployed on two different infra with above tech stack. I am trying to persist xml as string in xml datatype column into database. However, it works fine for one application without any issues but is giving below exception in another:

```
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding {prepstmnt -99242622 UPDATE T_QT SET QT_STTS_NM = ?, QT_XML_TXT = ?, QT_NUM = ?, UPDT_TS = ? WHERE QT_ID = ? [params=?, ?, ?, ?, ?]} [code=9402, state=S0001]
```

Tried following approaches to analyse the issue:

1. Compared JVM arguments in WAS admin console. - Both have empty JVM argument list.
2. Also tried overriding the JVM arguments with `-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 –Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
3. Compared SQL Server version in both environment. - No difference
4. Compared collation type in both evn at DB as well as table/column level - No difference `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
5. Tried to persist the xml which is failing for one of the environments into another. - Works fine.
6. Also tried to find the JPA version. It is using IBM provided JPA libraries. Its version is 2.1.1 and its same in both the env.
7. I also know one fix for this. It would work fine if I remove xml header tag and then persist that xml. But cant use this option as with no code changes it is working seamlessly in one of my environments.

Please help me identify if there can be anything else in application or  database server configurations or anything related to application server libraries other than JPA which can cause this issue.

Thanks in advance!